# Is the IFS Variable Changed in the following?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ifs

Below snippet is what I have for determining the path and the filename of where the file is present in the filesystem.

```
for index in "${!files[@]}"

    do
    (find . -type f -name "${files[index]}" -print0) 2>&1 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do
        if [[ ${line} == ${search_pattern}* ]]
        then
             relative_path=$(echo "$line"|awk '{print substr($0,2)}')
             file_path=$(echo "$(pwd)$relative_path" |awk -F/ '{$NF=""; print $0}'|sed -e 's/ /\//g')
             file_name=$(echo "$(pwd)$relative_path" |awk -F/ '{print $NF}')
    .................................................................
```

My question is regarding line,

`"while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' line; do"`

Earlier I was using a for loop over the find command. But there was a post on stackoverflow that this is better and more correct. I tried it, it worked but did not quite understand it. Does this line change the IFS in any way which would change effect the main shell? I tried to figure it out since I am not so well versed in SHELL scripting, I could not get what the line does.

I do not want to deploy this in a production system and then find out that other scripts are failing because IFS variable has been changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you perform the assignment to `IFS` inline with the `read` command, the value of the variable is changed for the duration of the command but does not remain changed after the command has completed.

Quoting the relevant section from [**Simple Commands** in the spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_01) (emphasis mine):

> If no command name results, variable assignments shall affect the current execution environment. Otherwise, the variable assignments shall be exported for the **execution environment of the command** and shall **not affect** the **current execution environment** (except for special built-ins). If any of the variable assignments attempt to assign a value to a read-only variable, a variable assignment error shall occur. See Consequences of Shell Errors for the consequences of these errors.

There are a great set of answers relating to this question on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/18886/67817).

Comment: And what if there are other scripts executing during that time (at which the value of the variable is changed) which make use of the IFS variable?

Comment: They will not be affected.